# Why do we have to use the as operator to call the GetScreenshot method

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

In the C# code below, where we're taking a screenshot using the Firefox webdriver, why do we have to use the as operator to call the `GetScreenshot` method?

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot; 
Screenshot screenShot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
screenShot.SaveAsFile(
    screenshotFileName,
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

`FirefoxDriver` inherits the `RemoteWebDriver` class and implements the `ITakesScreenshot` interface. The interface methods implemented by `RemoteWebDriver` can be called
directly without having to use the `as` operator on `FirefoxDriver` objects. The `GetScreenshot` method is implemented in FirefoxDriver.cs as shown:

```
public class FirefoxDriver : RemoteWebDriver, ITakesScreenshot
{
    //...
    public Screenshot GetScreenshot()
    {
        // Get the screenshot as base64.
        Response screenshotResponse = Execute(DriverCommand.Screenshot, null);
        string base64 = screenshotResponse.Value.ToString();

        // ... and convert it.
        return new Screenshot(base64);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't we be able to simply call this method like `driver.GetScreenshot()`?

C# Language Specification document states that explicit interface members can only be accessed via the interface type but I don't see how that applies to the `GetScreenshot` method here.

> In the previous EditBox class, the Paint method from the IControl
>   interface and the Bind method from the IDataBound interface are
>   implemented using public members. C# also supports explicit interface
>   member implementations, using which the class or struct can avoid
>   making the members public. An explicit interface member implementation
>   is written using the fully qualified interface member name. For
>   example, the EditBox class could implement the IControl.Paint and
>   IDataBound.Bind methods using explicit interface member
>   implementations as follows.

```
public class EditBox : IControl, IDataBound
{
    void IControl.Paint() {...}
    void IDataBound.Bind(Binder b) {...}
}
```

> Explicit interface members can only be accessed via the interface
>   type. For example, the implementation of IControl.Paint provided by
>   the previous EditBox class can only be invoked by first converting the
>   EditBox reference to the IControl interface type.

```
EditBox editBox = new EditBox();
editBox.Paint();                // Error, no such method
IControl control = editBox;
control.Paint();
```

Why the `as` operator is necessary in order for us to call the `GetScreenshot` method?

Answer (score 4):

Because it is implemented in `FirefoxDriver` and enforced by the `ITakeScreenshot` interface. You've declared it as `IWebDriver`. Since your variable is of type `IWebDriver` you cannot call a `FirefoxDriver` method on it. Therefore, they cast it to `ITakeScreenshot`.

To do what you want.. you could do this:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // make it a FirefoxDriver
driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";
ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver; // no cast. Not needed.
Screenshot screenShot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
```

You can simply use `driver.GetScreenshot()` as long as your variable is declared as `FirefoxDriver`.. not `IWebDriver` as it is currently.

Comment: I thought the whole point of object oriented programming was to model real life objects. Take a person who knows how to play golf. Whether you address this person as "father" or "Sir" or "CEO" depending on his occupation/social role, he doesn't all of a sudden lose his ability to play golf. That's the way it should be in OOP as well. We shouldn't have to call this person "golfer" in order to access his golfing abilities. If the golfer is also the "father" of someone we should be able to call him "father" and still access his golfing abilities.

Comment: I think you'll find it hard to find a resource that quotes "model real life objects". It is simply a way to basically model objects. There is no "real life" about it. It will help you to understand OO if you remove your association with "real life" from it.

Comment: In both ways we're calling the FirefoxDriver constructor but in only one way are we able to access all of the methods in this class. I don't know, it kind of seems to me like trickery. Pretending like we created a subset of something bigger when we still created the same object. Dishonest almost.